# BLANK handling in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What should be the code for handling blanks in snowflake?

for NULL, we do like

```
nvl (col1 , 'NA')
```

However, for blank or empty space etc what is the code in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

For handling '', ' ' or NULL the following code could be used:

```
SELECT col, COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(col), ''), 'NA')
FROM VALUES ('text'), (NULL), (''), (' '), ('   ') AS s(col);
```

Output:

[image]

Rationale:

- TRIM - removing spaces
- NULLIF - nullifying empty string
- COAELSCE - handling NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a CASE or IFF, for example:

```
select
    column1,
    case
        when column1='' then 'blank'
        when column1=' ' then 'space'
        else 'NA'
    end as result
from (values(''),(' '),('x')) v;
```

I get back:

[image]

With IFF you can try something like:

```
set a = ' ';
select iff($a = ' ', 'space', 'NA');
set b = '';
select iff($b = '', 'blank', 'NA');
```